# site link search box shopify

Tags: data-structures, shopify

I want to include an input box on site A; after I type in the query and press Enter, open a new tab to display the search results of B. It would be as if I had typed the search query into B directly.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a form to handle the search. Make it's action parameter the address of site B's search handler. Give it a target attribute of _blank

e.g.

```
<form action="https://storeB.myshopify.com/search" method="GET" target="_blank">
<input name="q" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

These are the basics. You can match the look of your current site by adapting the code from your theme. The code to look at may be in your theme's folders under templates/search.liquid.